# How does python application thread work with UWSGI?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have a python flask application running behind `uwsgi`. Below is the script I use to launch my application. As you can see that there is `--enable-threads` flag in the script. Based on uwsgi document, it says: `If you want to maintain Python threads support without starting multiple threads for your application, just add the --enable-threads option`. But I don't understand what it means by `threads support without starting multiple threads`. If I don't want to start multiple threads, why do I need to enable threads?

```
uwsgi \
  --uid uwsgi \
  --master \
  --plugins http,python3,stats_pusher_statsd \
  --http :8080 \
  --buffer-size 32768 \
  --enable-threads \
  --wsgi-file api/uwsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of this flag is to enable threads within your script while uWSGI threads is disabled. It is needed only if you implemented [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib2.html#multi-threading) in your script but don't want uWSGI to start its own threads.

[Original description](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#a-note-on-python-threads):

> If you start uWSGI without threads, the Python GIL will not be
>   enabled, so threads generated by your application will never run.
>
> <...>
>
> If you want to maintain Python threads support without starting
>   multiple threads for your application, just add the --enable-threads
>   option (or enable-threads = true in ini style).